# What is the notation (if any) for series probability inclusion?

Tags: statistics, notation

In statistics, what is the notation to use for an event $A$ in $B$ in $C$ in $D$, etc., where the series may continue for a large number of events? The following works for a few events:

$$A\cap B\cap C\cap D\cap\cdots$$

...However, this can become long and arduous for many events that might be considered. Is there any way to succinctly note a lengthy series like this (something like $\sum$ for a sum or $\prod$ for product series)?

The key here is in looking at multiplication laws, such as the following, and how to best note the series of multiplication steps for each $A_n$ in it:

$$p(A_1\cap \cdots \cap A_n)$$

I'd expect something like the following for "a" terms, but am not sure if this is correct (I don't believe the first term would work out here):

$$\prod_{n=1}^a p(A_1\mid A_1\cap A_n)$$

Comment: Are you looking for $\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i$?

Comment: Your question is very vague.  What do you mean by "$A$ in $B$ in $C$ in $D$, etc."? Does "in" mean "intersection"? In standard usage "$A$ in $B$" could mean $A\in B$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Your conditioning formula is a little off. It should be $$P(A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_n) = \prod_{j=1}^n P(A_j \mid A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_{j-1}),$$ if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: And since you ask about proper notation, notice that I changed $A\cap B\cap C\cap D....$ to $A\cap B\cap C\cap D\cap\cdots$, with a "$\cap$" after the $D$ and $\cdots$ rather than $\text{....}$.  Some might prefer $A\cap B\cap C\cap D\cap\ldots$, coded with \ldots, but just putting dots there doesn't get you proper spacing in LaTeX (although it might in MathJax, which is what is used here).  Where you had $A_1|A_2\cap A_n$ I changed it to $A_1\mid A_2\cap A_n$, coded with \mid.  Notice that that looks different. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: And @DPoole the last sentence in my comment above applies to you too.

Comment: Ah sorry....yes I mean as intersection and not as an element of.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHardy I never saw \mid before. It really cleans it up.

Comment: \mid and \nmid are also used for divisibility: $a\mid b$, $a\nmid b$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n$ you can write $\bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k$.  This is coded in MathJax and LaTeX as \bigcap, and in a "displayed" as opposed to "inline" context, it puts the subscripts and superscripts directly below and above the symbol, just as with $\sum$, thus:
$$
\bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k
$$
If you want the subscripts and superscripts to be formatted that way in an inline context, as $\displaystyle\bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k$, just put \displaystyle before it (that also affects the size).

You can also write
$$
T=\bigcap_{x\in S} A_x
$$
and that means that $a\in T$ if and only if for all $x\in S$, $a\in A_x$.  The set $S$ need not be countably infinite; it can be uncountably infinite.  For example, the intersection of all open intervals $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ for $\varepsilon>0$ is
$$
\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) = \{0\}.
$$